# Time variables magento

Tags: magento, date

How can I set the time notation to:

Day - Month - Year ( in dutch notation )

with the function: `<?php echo $_product->getSpecialTODate();?>`

in magento?

Current notation: Year-Month-Day time:time:time

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it: `<?php echo date('d F Y', strtotime($specialPriceToDate)); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try following piece of code instead of your code
`<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($_product->getSpecialTODate(), 'short', false); ?>`